# get only new contacts from google contacts api

Tags: java, google-api

I want to make a query to Google contacts that retrieves all NEW contacts since a given Date.

I am using google contacts api with the following scope: `https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/`

When I try to make a query that contains publishedMin parameter:

```
URL feedUrl = new URL("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full");
Query myQuery = new Query(feedUrl);
myQuery.setPublishedMin(startDateTime);

myQuery.setMaxResults(1000);

ContactFeed resultFeed = service.getFeed(myQuery, ContactFeed.class);
```

I get the following error:

```
com.google.gdata.util.ServiceForbiddenException: Forbidden
This service does not support the &#39;published-min&#39; parameter.

at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:605)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:564)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:560)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:538)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:536)
at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1135)
at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1077)
```

How else can I get the new contacts since a given date if I cannot use `publishedMin`.
Is there an alternative or a workaround for this?

I tried using updatedMin and then search every contact for `getPublished()` to filter them out but all the values are `null`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried updating your Java API lib? I'm guessing the current version wouldn't support requesting deprecated API features (like published-min). Maybe there's an underlying change in there that you need.

Comment: I am using the latest 1.22 version of the API. So it's not that.

Answer (score 1):

The Google Contacts API does not support a "published-min" parameter. Out of curiosity, where did you find this Java library that is still trying to use it? (if it is the latest version of a Google-provided library then it ought to be updated)

In the mean time, what you are looking for is the `updated-min` parameter: 
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_contacts_using_query_parameters

Comment: but that's the whole point of my question: if you use updatedMin then you get both updated contacts AND new contacts. I only want NEW contacts, and I cannot tell them apart.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. Creation time is not tracked separately from last-update time and so there's no way to specifically query it.